# Error Creating a Remote Project in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

In Eclipse 2019-09 I can SSH onto my PHP test server and view the files using RSE, but when I right click on a folder and select 'Create Remote Project' I get an error message saying 'Internal Error: Invalid Thread Access'.

The project seems to be created when I switch back to PHP view but it's empty.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong here and how to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After the project was created, I refreshed it and it worked.
Under 'Properties -> Resource -> Linked Resources' was an empty entry. I removed that and got rid of the error messages.